# What could stop Zend_Session::setSaveHandler from working

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm working a reasonably large zf1 project with multiple modules. We need to store the session state in the database for a new deployment. After a quick google we came across Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable and followed the simple example (almost exactly) at http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.session.savehandler.dbtable.html . I've placed the code in our application/Bootstrap.php and have checked it runs. However the database table is never populated with session data.

I thought something would be overriding the Zend_Session::setSaveHandler later in the code base but I can not find any other calls to that or Zend_Session::start();

Any suggestions on what might be wrong or how to investigate further?

edit with updated information:

here's how the relevant section of the bootstrap appears, currently just set up for dev mode.

```
protected function _initSessionDB()
{
  $db = Zend_Db::factory('Pdo_Mysql', array(
    'host' =>'localhost',
    'username' => '****',
    'password' => '****',
    'dbname' => '****'
  ));

  Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultAdapter($db);
  $config = array(
      'name' => 'session_state',
      'primary' => 'id',
      'modifiedColumn' => 'modified',
      'dataColumn' => 'data',
      'lifetimeColumn' => 'lifetime'
  );

  Zend_Session::setSaveHandler(new Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable($config));
  Zend_Session::start();
}
```

and the database has

```
mysql> explain session_state;
+----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id       | char(32) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| modified | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| lifetime | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| data     | text     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Most obvious question: if sessions aren't being saved in the DB, are they being saved somewhere else; i.e. on the file system?

Comment: sorry should of added that to the question, they are being stored in the default location on the vagrant machine which is /var/lib/php5/sess_*

Comment: Okay, so the save handler is not being used. Can you add the relevant part of the bootstrap to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out that the application I was working on sets up the FlashMessenger controller helper in the application/Bootstrap.

```
protected function _initAutoload()
{
  Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper(
      new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_FlashMessenger());
}
```

The `FlashMessenger` action helper makes its own call to `Zend_Session::start();` which seems to take priority over any later calls.

Simple solution is to add a `$this->bootstrap('sessionDB');` call before the `FlashMessenger` is created. for example,

```
protected function initFlashMessenger()
{
  $this->bootstrap('sessionDB');

  if (APPLICATION_ENV != 'testing')
    Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper(
      new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_FlashMessenger());
}
```

A better solution would be to not create the FlashMessenger in the bootstrap at all and just create it within controllers or appropriate base controller.